# SAS: Creating Tables Dynamically for different dates and table names in one go

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I'm stuck to something about creating tables dynamically by date filter.

I have SAS code for setting date filters before running main codes.

This it the date code;

```
data _null_;

/*ACTUAL DATES*/
R_act_beg=intnx('month',today(),-12,'beginning');
call symput('R_act_beg',R_act_beg);
R_act_end=intnx('month',today(),-1,'end');
call symput('R_act_end',R_act_end);
name_m=put(month(intnx('month',today(),-1)),z2.);
call symput('name_m',name_m);
name_y_act=put(year(intnx('month',today(),-1)),z4.);
call symput('name_y_act',name_y_act);
nameR_act=name_m||substr(name_y_act,3,4);
call symput('nameR_act',nameR_act);
```

And this is the one of main codes;

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE DATA.PREMIUM&nameR_act  AS 
SELECT t1.POLICY_NO, 
      /* SUM_of_PREMIUM */
        (SUM(t1.PREMIUM)) FORMAT=22.2 AS SUM_of_PREMIUM
  FROM WH.V_PRODUCT t1
  WHERE t1.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN &R_act_beg AND &R_act_end AND t1.PRODUCT_NO IN 
       (
       '421',
       '423',
       '424',
       '425',
       '404',
       '433',
       '430',
       '444',
       '441',
       '443',
       '453'
       )
  GROUP BY t1.POLICY_NO;
QUIT;
```

So I should run about ten main codes retrospectively for 12 months. Is it possible to create a date code dynamically in order to running main codes for 12 months in one go.

Comment: why don't you enclose the main code in  a macro and pass on the dates parameters one by one - 12 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build on the following code

- Step1
  : Creating the `dataset` which contains all the 12 dates.

Not sure how are you calculating the dates for all the 12 months,
So I have assumed `dataset All_dates` contains all your dates
with variables - `R_act_beg, R_act_end ,name_m,name_y_act,nameR_act`.
This dataset contains 12 records one for each month.

- Step2: Creating `macro variables` for all the 12 months in one go

---

```
proc sql;
select R_act_beg into: R_act_beg1 - :R_act_beg12 from all_dates;
select R_act_end into: R_act_end1 - :R_act_end12 from all_dates;
select name_m into: name_m1 - :name_m12 from all_dates;
select name_y_act into: name_y_act1 - :name_y_act12 from all_dates;
select nameR_act into: nameR_act1 - :nameR_act12 from all_dates;
quit;
```

- Step3: Running the code 12 times by using the `do loop and &&`

---

```
%macro run_12_times;

%do i=1 %to 12; 
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE DATA.PREMIUM&nameR_act&&i.  AS 
SELECT t1.POLICY_NO, 
      /* SUM_of_PREMIUM */
        (SUM(t1.PREMIUM)) FORMAT=22.2 AS SUM_of_PREMIUM
  FROM WH.V_PRODUCT t1
  WHERE t1.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN &R_act_beg&&i. AND &R_act_end&&i. AND t1.PRODUCT_NO IN 
       (
       '421',
       '423',
       '424',
       '425',
       '404',
       '433',
       '430',
       '444',
       '441',
       '443',
       '453'
       )
  GROUP BY t1.POLICY_NO;

  %end;

  %mend;
%run_12_times;
```

Comment: Thanks @NEOmen, i've a problem with my sas account. when i fix it i'm gonna try it and feedback to you. Thans again.

Comment: Hi @NEOmen, there is no problem for step 1 and 2 but at step 3 sas code is getting crashed. a part of error log;
'..5         %run_16_times;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NAMER_ACT not resolved.
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "RUN_16_TIMES".
75                                          &nameR_act&&i.  AS  SELECT  t1.POLICE_NO,  
                                            22
                                            200
75       ! FORMAT=22.2 AS SUM_of_PREMIUM       FROM WH.V_PRODUCT t1       WHERE t1.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN &R_act_beg&&i. AND...'

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem whereby @NEOmen 's answer but i want to fix a slip up at "Step 3".
"Step 1" and "Step 2" completely correct. "Step 3" should be as follows.
Thanks again.

```
%macro run_12_times;

%do i=1 %to 12; 
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE DATA.PREMIUM&&nameR_act&i.  AS 
SELECT t1.POLICY_NO, 
      /* SUM_of_PREMIUM */
        (SUM(t1.PREMIUM)) FORMAT=22.2 AS SUM_of_PREMIUM
  FROM WH.V_PRODUCT t1
  WHERE t1.ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN "&&R_act_beg&i."d AND "&&R_act_end&i."d AND t1.PRODUCT_NO IN 
       (
       '421',
       '423',
       '424',
       '425',
       '404',
       '433',
       '430',
       '444',
       '441',
       '443',
       '453'
       )
  GROUP BY t1.POLICY_NO;

  %end;

  %mend;
%run_12_times;
```